# How to create a polygon on Google map using list of GPS location

Tags: google-maps, gps, polygon

I have a list of customer (GPS coordinates) for each salesman in excel file. I want to create a polygon in Google map that shows area of each salesman in map.

Is there any tool that shows my salesman area in the Google map ?
[image: Route 22]

Answer (score 1):

For the first step it is easier to use Google Earth.
To display data you need a google kml file.

Create a placemark, and use the Polygon.

More, see https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

To display a kml in google maps, the file has to be located on a server reachable by an url.
Ffor goggle earth a local file on your disk is sufficient.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have converted my excel to kml file and opened in Google earth after when I click on add polygon nothing happens. I want system to create for me a polygon based on gps location. is there any way ?

Comment: The kml file must contain a Polygon element, containing the cooridnates. Start creating such a kml file manually. Look at the example kml files. Once it works manually you can create the kml automatically, writing an Excel Basic script or using an programming language.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you may want to use a concave hull algorithm. You can read more in depth at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39205/converting-point-sets-to-polygon-boundaries

In JavaScript, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/concaveman.

[image]